# Custom Action Bar with OnCreateOptionsMenu added doesnt Center title Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created custom action bar which has ImageView (on left) and TextView (on right). However I have different fragments within activity for few of them I need to show onCreateOptionsMenu. If there is onCreateOptionsMenu title of Action Bar is pushed to left and doesn't not look in center.

It looks like following  action bar + onCreateOptionsMenu:

[image]

As you see Downloads text is inclined bit towards left side when onCreateOptions menu is added.

If no onCreateOptions  text is center as shown below:

[image]

Here is my custom action bar code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menubutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#22c064"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't to put onCreateOptionsMenu as imageView in custom action bar as it will complicate things.

Comment: Have you looked at `Toolbar` in API 21? http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: I note that you have five questions, including this one, in which you are asking for priority treatment over other questions. Please don't do this - remember that readers here are predominantly volunteers, and they will answer questions that they find interesting, at their leisure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menubutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/navigation_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menubutton"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#22c064"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @vo12 try this time aligned to image right ..hope it ll solve your issue.answer editted